# Assign Jackson-Jsog's @id to a member variable

Tags: jackson, jsog

Is it possible to assign the jsog's @id value to an member variable in a POJO class?

For example I have a json:

```
"user": {
   "@id": "1",
   "name": "John Doe"
}
```

And Java class

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=JSOGGenerator.class)
public class User {

   private String id; // this is null

   private String name;

   // getters and setters ...
}
```

I tried `@JsonProperty("@id")` but it my `id` still is `null`. Does anyone have an experience with this? I don't want to add another `id` field into my JSON as it makes it ugly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier "@id" is not a valid Java property since it begins the '@' character. This is a nice feature since it won't conflict with any properties you have on your object.

I'm not sure how you transform that property into a Java property but you probably don't want to. The @id is purely for serialization/deserialization of the object graph; the @id value may change with each serialization if the object graph has changed.

You can't use the @id as an identifier of a object in a meaningful way outside of the serialization. You probably want a real ID that doesn't change based on serialization.